# Get transactions that failed or were never committed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transaction

Is there anywhere I can look to find failed transactions in SQL server 2012?

Answer (score 5):

No, SQL Server does not maintain any history about transactions that were aborted / rolled back that is trivial to get to and doesn't introduce additional potential problems (as outlined in [@ooutwire's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44845/1186)). Or even transactions that have been committed.

You will have to perform your own logging within your error handling, or capture specific transaction-related events using server-side trace or Extended Events.

Trace:

[image]

Extended events:

[image]

Comment: Sure it does, they are in the log file and log backup files.

Comment: @ooutwire and how do you get to those easily? And how do you get to them if they are no longer in the log? Those log records are transient at best.

Comment: See my answer. The best way is to create frequent log backups. I would agree that such a solution is not ideal; but I see no reason why I would be searching all the time in prod for aborted transactions. If that is the desire, than a trace or XEvent would seem the prudent solution.

Comment: I saw your answer, of course. I said *easily* and also should have said *reliably*. :-)

Comment: I think fn_dump_dblog is easy and reliable if one likes pain =)

Comment: I'm with @AaronBertrand on this one.  With the trouble it'll take to comb through transaction logs (**Note: not what they are intended for**) you might as well just create a lightweight XE session for this troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4):

When you say "failed" transactions, what exactly do you mean?

If you want to see current transactions on the instance, you can utilize the [`sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174302.aspx) DMV.

Also, `sys.dm_exec_sessions` has the `open_transaction_count` that can give you this information by session.  Below is a diagnostic query to pull all user processes that have open transactions:

```
select 
    s.session_id,
    s.login_name,
    s.open_transaction_count,
    st.text as most_recent_sql_text
from sys.dm_exec_sessions s
inner join sys.dm_exec_connections c
on s.session_id = c.session_id
outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) st
where s.is_user_process = 1
and s.open_transaction_count > 0;
```

This information can also be pulled from `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`:

```
select
    session_id,
    is_user_transaction,
    open_transaction_count
from sys.dm_tran_session_transactions;
```

If you want to capture when transactions were rolled back (assuming so much by your desire for "failed" transactions) you can capture the Extended Events `rollback_tran_completed` event.  If you're looking for an "everything" view of transactions, you can capture the `sql_transaction` event, which as defined by SQL Server is

> Occurs when a SQL Server transaction begins, completes, rolls back or executes a savepoint. Use this event to monitor transaction behavior when troubleshooting applications, triggers or stored procedures.

Answer (score 4):

You can use fn_dblog() and find the transaction IDs for aborted transactions as well as a host of other useful information.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fn_dblog (NULL, NULL)
WHERE Operation = 'LOP_ABORT_XACT';
GO
```

It scans all transaction log in the active portion of the log. This can be over-ridden using trace flag 2537, which will allow you to go back as far as possible to the start of the oldest "un-reused" VLF. Be careful when using this function, since it scans the log randomly and the log cannot change when the scan is happening; so, you may see log growth.

You can also use fn_dump_dblog against a log backup file.